# Why switch statement counts integers as whitespace character in a digit counting C program?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was experimenting with what happens when you remove `break` statements in a specific switch statement in the code below. I know removing `break` statements causes execution to flow through to the next case.

But I am confused why the following program will count digits as whitespace characters, see below

```
int main() {
    int c , i , nwhite , nother , ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF){
        switch (c)
        {
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
        case ' ': case '\n': case '\t':
            nwhite++;
        default:
            nother++;
            
        }
    }
    printf("digits= ");
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    }
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
    return 0;
}
```

Input :

> farai 1234is 34

Output:

> digits=  0 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0, white space = 9, other = 16

Why are the digits '1234' and '34' counting as whitespace?

Comment: because you have no `break;` in your cases

Comment: *"I know removing break statements causes execution to flow through to the next case."* - You answered your own question, albeit unknowingly.

Comment: I just realized that, haha!

Comment: Did you start with `case '0': break; case '1': break;` ...?

Comment: @Joshua No, I started with ```break;``` right after  ```ndigit[c-'0']++;```

Comment: Fnechz, notice `other = 16`, the count of all characters entered.

Answer (score 1):

You removed your `break;` statements after the operation code.

```
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
```

Very good.

```
        case ' ': case '\n': case '\t':
         nwhite++;
```

But without a break it goes on to the next `case` label and falls through to the next statement. Thus it increments both `ndigit[]` and `nwhite` You really want

```
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            ndigit[c-'0']++;
            break;
```

so it doesn't do that. (Sometimes falling through is what you want. Just not this time.)

Comment: They did not forget. The very first sentence of the question states they deliberately removed them.